# Estimating Number of Zeros Using Sturm' Comparison Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Q. Let $x:[0,3 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non zero solution of the ODE $$x^{\prime \prime}(t)+e^{t^{2}} x(t)=0,$$ for $t \in[0,3 \pi]$. Then the cardinality of the set $\{t \in[0,3 \pi]: x(t)=0\}$ is

(1) greater than or equal to 2

(2) equal to 1

(3) greater than or equal to 3

(4) equal to 2

My attempt and doubt:

The Sturm's comparison with the ODE$$z''(t)+z(t)=0,$$ says option 1 is true and thereby option 2 is false since the solution $z(t)=\sin (t)$ has zeros at $\pi, 2\pi$ and $3\pi$ on $(0,3\pi]$. I can consider only the interval $[\alpha, 3\pi],~0<\alpha<\pi,$ to satisfy the hypothesis ($e^{t^2}>1$) of Sturm's comparison theorem. How to deal with this issue to confirm the truth values of options 3 and 4?

Comment: All these variants are so far away from the truth that it is nearly ridiculous. A direct application of the comparison theorem shows that there are more than $10^{17}$ roots already in the interval $[2.9\pi,3\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Sturm Comparison is overkill if you are simply trying to select the answer to a multiple-choice question. Since the factor $ e^{t^2}$ is enormous for a large portion of the interval under consideration, this system acts like a harmonic oscillator with a very stiff spring constant. It will oscillate like crazy, and the solution must change sign many many times. Only choice (3) can be correct. You can try numerical modeling should you wish to confirm this.